# Can I make update-alternatives keep 2 commands in sync?

Tags: alternatives

I have 2 commands that I switch between using `update-alternatives` on Debian. My problem is that each command also has an autocompleter command that has to be switched at the same time the command is switched. Is there some way I can keep the 2 commands managed in a single "alternative", so that when I switch commands (using `update-alternatives --set ...`) the autocompleter is switched as well?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make the autocompleter a slave link. See [the manual](https://manpages.debian.org/bookworm/dpkg/update-alternatives.1#:%7E:text=It%20is%20often%20useful,group.) for details (look for "changed as a group").

In your package's `postinst` script:

```
update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/someprogram someprogram /usr/bin/foo-someprogram $PRIORITY \
    --slave /usr/share/zsh/site-functions/_someprogram /usr/share/zsh/site-functions/_foo-someprogram
```

where $PRIORITY is the numeric priority of the alternative when automatic selection takes place.